# Inertia subgroup of a p-adic Lie group is infinite

Tags: galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, lie-groups, p-adic-number-theory

It is stated [here](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/%7Epierre.colmez/sen-an.pdf) (very end of the 3rd page) that the inertia subgroup of the p-adic Lie group ${\rm Gal}(K_{\infty}/K)$ is infinite when the dimension of ${\rm Gal}(K_{\infty}/K)$ is greater than $2$ (here $K$ is a finite extension of $\mathbf{Q}_p$, $K\subset K_{\infty}\subset\overline{\mathbf{Q}_p}$ and $K_{\infty}/K$ is Galois). It is stated as obvious but I don't get why it is true. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The quotient $\mathrm{Gal}(K_\infty/K)/I$ is topologically cyclic: it's generated by a lift of the Frobenius element.

Comment: @Mathmo123 ${\rm Gal}(K_{\infty}/K)/I$ is isomorphic to ${\rm Gal}(k_{\infty}/k)$, but why is it topologically cyclic in a general setting ? can you please expand a bit on that ?

Comment: Galois groups of finite fields are always topologically cyclic, generated by the frobenius element $x\mapsto x^{|k|}$.